# Copy artifacts of each module in multi-module project to specific folder

Tags: maven-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maven multi-module project - copying all “package” JARS from submodules into parent/target/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292752/maven-multi-module-project-copying-all-package-jars-from-submodules-into-par)

I have an pom structure:

```
project1
    |
    |______ pom.xml
    |______ module 1
    |          |_____ pom.xml
    |          |_____ dist
    |                  |_____ bin
    |                  |_____ lib
    |______ module 2
    |          |_____ pom.xml
    |          |_____ dist
    |                  |_____ bin
    |                  |_____ lib
    |______ dist
    |         |____ bin
    |         |____ lib


Requirements:
     +  When build each module, bundle file will be copied to its' dist/bin and dependencies copied to its' dist/lib
     + When build project1, bundle file of each module will be copied to project1/dist/bin and dependencies of all modules copied to project/dist/lib
```

Can we achieve this??? If it can, how we do it???

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-copy-example . The only thing i changed is not to use a a folder like dist i use target/dist in the maven style.